# *ngIf div show hide subscribe Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to show a div as long as the function does not return any document from a certain collection of firestore, ie zero. If there is any document this div must be hidden.

Any idea how I can achieve this? I tried the following but it does not work:

**service.ts**

```
getEventosPropios() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.eventosPropios = this.afs.collection('eventos', ref => ref
    .where('autorId', '==', user.uid)
    ).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Evento;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
    return this.eventosPropios;
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
eventosPropios: any;
eventosLista = true;

constructor( public fs: FirebaseService ) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.eventosPropios = this.fs.getEventosPropios();
  this.eventosPropios.subscribe(() => this.eventosLista = false);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="eventosLista">
  ...        
</div>
<div *ngFor="let evento of eventosPropios | async">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Is the div still visible after setting `this.eventosLista = false` ?

Comment: Is the function returning correct values ?

Comment: @RanikaNisal returns the documents if it meets the filter condition `.where('autorId', '==', user.uid)`

Comment: @ashish.gd after this the div is not shown but neither is any document of the collection shown. That is, it should be shown or one or the other

Comment: Try making this.eventosLista an observable as well and use an async pipe at the ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

The documents are not shown since you are iterating on the returned `Subscription` from the `this.fs.getEventosPropios()` method.

Changing the code slightly to use the `result` returned by the `getEventosPropios()` method should fix the issue.

#### component.ts

```
eventosPropiosSub: Subscription; //should be use to unsubscribe later
eventosPropios: any;
eventosLista = true;

constructor( public fs: FirebaseService ) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.eventosPropiosSub = this.fs.getEventosPropios()
    .subscribe((result) => {
        this.eventosPropios = result; // assign the returned result
        this.eventosLista = false
    });
}
```